# Nova Compute LXD and Linux Bridge Agent on Ubuntu 16.04.1 and Documentation

Tags: networking, juju, openstack, lxd

As I could not make a compute node work out of the box with lxd with 16.04 for networking I was wondering if I could be pointed to the right direction.

Two questions:

1) Does nova-compute-lxd work with Linux Bridge Agent on Ubuntu 16.04.1?

According to recent posts I could read that early versions would only work with OVS and that there was a patch around to use veth vs tap. I have successfully installed nova-compute-lxd, nova instances can be created but there is an issue with networking: although fixed ip and and floating ip can be allocated, there is no network connectivity although tcpdump shows relevant packets reaching the underlying interfaces. I suspect that there is an issue with Linux Bridge that might not yet be supported.

2) Is there detailed documentation for nova-compute-lxd setup with networking?

Although LXD seems a quite powerful solution, detailed documentation for a basic reference setup would be nice, especially with respect to LXD bridge and networking on the compute node and LXD setup for Openstack in general as one may one to try it to replace a KVM based compute node and not necessarily try a trial bundle at the first place.

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: Went down the route to switch to Openvswitch with some headaches but successful in the end. Disappointment is that mitaka/stable does not seem to  support volumes with LXD. However whilst looking in the master branch it may be that now linux bridge is supported (see nova-lxd vif.py)...

Comment: You mean neutron-linuxbridge-agent? For me it gives errors like `modprobe: FATAL: Module ebtables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic`.

Comment: Yes I mean neutron-linuxbridge-agent. I can't remember the details of the troubleshooting except that it seemed to point to vif.py but we just replaced nova kvm with nova lxd and we were using linux-bridge-agent with kvm and that was fin. We did not explore further and went down the route of using neutron-openvswitch-agent.